# SQL: For the same value of A, if two or more values of B exist, and one of the B values is null; show all combinations of A, B and C

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

looking for how to go about this in SQL.

For the same value of A, if two or more values of B exist, and one of the B values is null; show all combinations of A, B and C.

Table:

```
A   B   C  
1   2   3 
4   5   6  
7   8   9  
1  null 4
1   2   4
9   3   5
9  null 7
```

Expected Result:

```
A   B   C 
1   2   3
1  null 4
1   2   4
9   3   5
9  null 7
```

ThankYou :)

Better example
[image: Input and expected output]

Comment: firstly, can you share what you have tried?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: [tag:mysql] or [tag:sqlite]? They're two different products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another solution:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM #testdata t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #testdata WHERE A = t1.A AND B IS NULL)
AND   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #testdata WHERE A = t1.A AND B IS NOT NULL)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8b26aa/1)

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements are slightly tricky.  One way we can phrase it is that, in order to be retained, an `A` group has to have a distinct `B` count plus an optional increment by one for nulls present which is two or more.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT A
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY A
    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT B) > 0 AND
        MAX(CASE WHEN B IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.A = t2.A;
```

### Demo

The demo is for MySQL but it so happens that the same query should run on SQLite as well.

Comment: Hi Tim. I've added a picture into my question. Hope it is clearer now. Could you take a look?

Comment: @Rex Your question was never unclear to me.

Comment: This will also return a group where two distinct values, but no NULL exist, i.e. the VODAFONE group from the example.

Comment: @dnoeth I misread the question to think that the OP wanted 2 or more of non NULL B values or NULL values, the latter being counted only once.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT B) > 0` = `COUNT(B) > 0`

Answer (score 3):

This should return your expected result, simply compare the count of *all* vs. *NOT NULL* rows:

Based on [Tim's fiddle](http://rextester.com/JGHR64245):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT A
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY A
    HAVING COUNT(*) > COUNT(B)
       AND COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.A = t2.A;
```

Or as a simle Subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE A IN
 (
   SELECT A
   FROM yourTable
   GROUP BY A
   HAVING COUNT(*) > COUNT(B)
      AND COUNT(*) > 1
 )
```

See [fiddle](http://rextester.com/IBXR9708)

Answer (score 0):

Based on example you just need simple `group by` clause and `join` them

```
select * from table t
inner join (
     select provider from table t
     group by provider 
     having count(*) > 1 and 
            sum(case when service is null then 1 else 0 END) >= 1
) c on c.provider  = t.provider
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen.. I don't know what query u have wrote before 20 minute, if same then let me know to delete this post or post something different.